# Use ID of Play Server in a conf file included in application.conf

Tags: java, configuration, playframework

Let's say I have a conf file called extra.conf.  I add it to the Play Server's application.conf like this:

```
@include.extra = extra.conf
```

And extra.conf looks like this:

```
foo=bar
```

The following code returns `bar` as expected:

```
Play.configuration.getProperty("foo");
```

However, if I want to prefix the property with the server id like this:

```
%someid.foo=bar
```

and start the server with the above id:

```
play run --%someid
```

The code can no longer obtain the foo property.

If I move `%someid.foo=bar` directly into the application.conf instead of having it in the extra.conf file, it works again.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to get the original scenario to work where I prefix a property with the server id and have that property included via a conf file which is not application.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to be a bug. 
You should submit it on play.lighthouseapp.com